# How to improve feed in a location discovery app?

Tags: android, machine-learning, location, foursquare

I am creating a FourSquare clone based on their API, it is meant purely for learning purpose, what I want to do is improve places of interest suggestion by user's interaction data, here is how I think it can be done, not sure though if it is the correct way.

1. The user starts the app, they are shown a bunch of places of interest, he/she clicks on a place, at this moment I store the name of that place as well as the category that place belongs to, maybe the distance from his location to that place.
2. The user searches for a place, the result gets populated, I store the top 5 (considering them to the most relevant) result's data.
3. The user clicks on a category, I store that category.
4. The user uses filters, I store those filters under proper category.

Now all this data will be feed to Heroku/AWS based program that will use that data to create a database that will store information about about each user, these information will be, the maximum and minimum distance they look for.
The categories they are interested in, the location they like to visit most.

Is this an optimized method to do this? Now really sure, also is this is even legal? I mean I will store user's interaction data, also how should I go about creating the user's unique id, storing Facebook authorization info is I guess is not allowed.

Is there a tool or library that helps in such tasks?

Comment: In what sense are you worried that your project may not be legal? Where are you based (legality depends almost entirely on jurisdiction)?

Comment: Well, not sure if it is okay to monitor user data, secondly storing the OAuth credentials of a user, well I won't exactly be storing the user credentials, just some sort of key that can trace back the user's facebook id.

Comment: You can use people's data in the manner in which you have described in your privacy policy. Basically, obey the data protection legislation in your country, be completely honest with users as to how you use their data, don't do anything that would constitute obvious misuse, and put the user in control of their data.

Comment: Okay, got that one.
But how about the problem in hand?
Is the way I think is correct one? Is there a tool for it?